# How to remove vocals so I can download only the instrumental of a song through python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pydub

I am struggling with exporting a new audio file that only contains the instrumental of the song and no vocals.

I'm currently attempting to run this bit of code:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play


sound_stereo = AudioSegment.from_file(file="Song.wav", format="wav")
sound_monoL = sound_stereo.split_to_mono()[0]
sound_monoR = sound_stereo.split_to_mono()[1]

# Phase inversion of the Right audio file
sound_monoR_inv = sound_monoR.invert_phase()

# Merge two L and R_inv files, this cancels out the centers
sound_CentersOut = sound_monoL.overlay(sound_monoR_inv)

# Export merged audio file
fh = sound_CentersOut.export("TwinFlameEdit.wav", format="wav")
```

The error it is giving me is:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/kf/367f3q912qs6dgqw9qlbqhn40000gn/T/ipykernel_76230/604316813.py in <module>
      5 sound_stereo = AudioSegment.from_file(file="Song.wav", format="wav")
      6 sound_monoL = sound_stereo.split_to_mono()[0]
----> 7 sound_monoR = sound_stereo.split_to_mono()[1]
      8 
      9 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Could anyone tell me how to fix this? I have also tried using Librosa but not gotten much success with that either. Ask me anything that might need more clarity to understand the situation, thank you.

Comment: Did you consider the possibility that the sound file is already mono? What do you expect `.split_to_mono` to do in this case? Anyway, I don't understand what the question title has to do with the code you are showing, and I'm not clear on the description of the problem. How many sound files do you intend to work with? For each, how many channels should it have? What sound do you expect in each file? In each channel?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank you for your comment, what I'm trying to achieve is a code where I input an audio file of a song with vocals and an instrumental but after running the code, the output is with the vocals removed and only the instrumental remaining, like a vocal-remover.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `wav` file is already mono, so it can't be splitted. From the [`pydub` source code](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/audio_segment.py#L1063):

```python
def split_to_mono(self):
    if self.channels == 1:
        return [self]
```

I'm not sure what your expected output is, but you might consider using the same channel for both Left and Right, i.e.:

```python
...
sound_monoL = sound_stereo.split_to_mono()[0]
sound_monoR = sound_stereo.split_to_mono()[0]
...
```

Note that I didn't use `sound_monoR = sound_monoL` as that may (or may not) lead to unexpected mutable object issues.

Comment: Thank you for this, I want my output to be an audio file that does not contain the vocals on my song, only the background music. Having both be [0] exports a file, however there is no sound at all, it is the same length as the original but with no sound.

Comment: The sample code you are using is for stereo sound files only. Try again with a stereo recording.

Answer (score -1):

Your code does works just like intended, successfully canceling the center channel:

[see screenshot: input -> output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT1cC.png)

You end up with the mono "[side signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_encoding)": S = L - R

Under the hood, pydub uses either *avconv* or *ffmeg* to do the encoding, see .../pydub/utils.py:170

```
def get_encoder_name():
"""
Return enconder default application for system, either avconv or ffmpeg
"""
if which("avconv"):
    return "avconv"
elif which("ffmpeg"):
    return "ffmpeg"
else:
    # should raise exception
    warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
    return "ffmpeg"
```

I do not have avconv on my mac so it defaults to using ffmpeg, throws me a RuntimeWarning, but all is good:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydub/utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
```

Try installing [ffmeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html), forcing pydub to use it and give it a shot
... or go for it and do it all by yourself, without pydub:

**Pseudocode:**

```
open input file
read wav header
read wav data chunk
open output file
write modified header (2 Ch -> 1 Ch)
write modified data chunk
for sample in song:
    sample = sample_in.L - sample_in.R
```